# custom function to split data for list of variables

Tags: r

Hi I am looking for a function which can split a dataset when we pass a list of vectors as a input parameters. lets say i have data frame like below.

```
data<-data.frame( Q1=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA),
                  Q2=c(1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA),
                  Q3=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA),
                  Q4=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1),
                  Q5=c(NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1),
                  Q6=c(1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1),
                  Q7=c(NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA),
                  region=c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,NA,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2)
)
```

after labelling it

```
data$Q5<-factor(data$Q5, levels=c(1), labels=c("USA"))
data$Q6<-factor(data$Q6, levels=c(1), labels=c("Worlds"))
data$region<-factor(data$region, levels=c(1,2), labels=c("ALL","Special"))
```

and lets say I have a list of vectors like

```
lst <- c(total,Q6,Q5,.....)
```

The function will create a list of subset of data frames for lst

if lst have total then whole data (Original data) for Q6 filter all non NA values and then create a whole subset for Q6 for Q5 filter all non NA values and then create a whole subset for Q5

input parameter for function would be like

```
split_data(dataset= data, list_d= lst)
```

for this the output required will be list of data frames

data <- data

```
Q6 <- data %>% filter(Q6==1)
Q5 <- data %>% filter(Q5==1)
lstt <- list(total,V8,Q5)
lstt
```

Comment: What is your list of vectors (i.e. that `lst <- c(total,Q6,Q5,.....)`)? Is it just a character vector like `c("total", "Q6", "Q5")`?

Comment: yes its a character vector,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
split_data <- function(df, lst) {
  lapply(lst, function(x, df) {
    if (x == "total")
      return(df)
    df[!is.na(df[[x]]), ]
  }, df)
}
```

Output

```
> split_data(data, c("total", "Q5", "Q6"))
[[1]]
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 region
1   1  1  1  1 NA  1 NA      1
2   1  1  1 NA  1 NA  1      2
3  NA  1 NA NA NA  1  1      1
4  NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA      1
5  NA  1 NA NA  1 NA  1      1
6  NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA      2
7  NA NA NA NA  1 NA  1      1
8  NA NA  1 NA  1 NA  1      2
9   1 NA NA NA NA  1 NA      2
10 NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA      1
11 NA  1 NA  1  1  1  1      2
12 NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1     NA
13 NA  1 NA NA  1  1 NA      1
14 NA  1 NA NA  1  1 NA      1
15 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA      2
16 NA NA NA NA  1  1  1      2
17 NA NA  1 NA NA  1  1      2
18  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA      1
19 NA  1 NA  1  1 NA  1      1
20 NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA      1
21 NA NA NA  1  1  1 NA      2

[[2]]
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 region
2   1  1  1 NA  1 NA  1      2
5  NA  1 NA NA  1 NA  1      1
7  NA NA NA NA  1 NA  1      1
8  NA NA  1 NA  1 NA  1      2
11 NA  1 NA  1  1  1  1      2
13 NA  1 NA NA  1  1 NA      1
14 NA  1 NA NA  1  1 NA      1
16 NA NA NA NA  1  1  1      2
19 NA  1 NA  1  1 NA  1      1
21 NA NA NA  1  1  1 NA      2

[[3]]
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 region
1   1  1  1  1 NA  1 NA      1
3  NA  1 NA NA NA  1  1      1
6  NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA      2
9   1 NA NA NA NA  1 NA      2
11 NA  1 NA  1  1  1  1      2
13 NA  1 NA NA  1  1 NA      1
14 NA  1 NA NA  1  1 NA      1
16 NA NA NA NA  1  1  1      2
17 NA NA  1 NA NA  1  1      2
21 NA NA NA  1  1  1 NA      2
```